# Using VBA to search an array of data, and once matches are found mark it as "X" in a matrix on same workbook different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, matrix

The title is quite exhaustive but heres what im looking for.

On sheet 1 it will search through the weeks row, as it searched each row when a value that is greater than 0 is met, it will look up to the column name which is a Job Plan number. Once it does this, on another sheet where a matrix is present, It will output the string "x" in week 1 column to match the JP.

I will put some pics to help better.

[image]

^ This is the first sheet that needs to go through each week row and find the green highlight or value > 0 and match it to the blue row which is JP.

[image]

Once it matches, it will come to this matrix and it'll "X" off anything that had a value under the column weeks.

Any help would be great, im new to VBA and this is an intense project.

Comment: Why do you need VBA? It sounds like an excel IF formula would work. `=IF(COUNTIF(E:E,">0")>0,"x","")` which translates to: "If there is a value greater than 0 in range E:E, this cell value is "x", otherwise its blank." Change E:E as needed.

Comment: What is E:E?. And its because VBA would automate it for a large amount of data. I only took a screenshot of a portion to help explain. Also, I need the X to show up under the correct week for all true values for the different JP's and put an x on a different sheet not the same one

Comment: E:E is Column E. And this formula would handle a large amount of data. You would put one of these in every cell that might receive an "x" and then reference the ranges that would cause it to have that "x". You can put a thousand of these formulas on a sheet with no problems. 

And of course you can reference other sheets and multiple ranges. Heres an example of referencing two other sheets `=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!C:Z,">0")+COUNTIF(Sheet3!J:K,">0") >0,"x","")`

Comment: The whole point is to avoid putting this formula in each cell. Using VBA to automatically find values >0 in the first sheet and going to the second sheet to match it and place the X is the project. Putting that =IF function in every cell that could have an X defeats the purpose. I understand what you are saying and it makes sense for very small sets of data, im talking over 1000+ points of data

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do it in VBA. Since I don't know where everything is in your sheets, the ranges will need to be adjusted. I have left notes to help accomplish that.

```vb
Sub LoopDemo()
    Dim weeknum As Integer
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rFind  As Range
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    
    Set SearchRange = Sheet1.Range("Q411:EC775")
    'Set this to match your data
    
    For Each cell In SearchRange
    'Looping through, cell by cell
        If IsNumeric(cell.Value) And cell.Value > 0 Then
        'Looking for positive numbers
            
            weeknum = cell.Offset(0, 16 - cell.Column)
            '16 = Column P - Change "16" to your Week # column.
            
            On Error Resume Next
            'Searching sheet2 column "A" for the Job Plan #
            Set rFind = Sheet2.Columns(1).Find(what:=cell.Offset(1 - cell.Row).Text)
            
            If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
                rFind.Offset(0, 4 + weeknum) = "x"
                'Putting the x into the cell
                'Change 4 to match the number of columns before the "W1" column
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: On my separate sheet where the big data is (screenshot 1) is that the range I highlight in Set SearchRange? Do I only label the data itself?

Comment: Im using your code but I have a feeling i'm inputting wrong data due to misinterpretation. My data goes from Q411:EC775 it seems (this is ONLY including the numerical values inside the matrix as shown in pic 1). Im confused about all the offset stuff

Comment: I will edit my answer to match the data range Q411:EC775. What about sheet2? Which column # is the "W1" column?

Comment: The line `weeknum = cell.Offset(0, 16 - cell.Column)` translates to "set weeknum equal to the value of the cell in column P for this row"

Comment: The `.Find` argument `what:=cell.Offset(1 - cell.Row).Text` translates to "Search for the value found in Row 1 in the column of this cell". For example, if the cell was X578 then the offset would look at X1. I assumed your Job Plan #'s were in Row 1.

Comment: For sheet W1 starts on column E which is 5 and what I want it to match to is the Job Plan which is column A which is 1

Comment: All of these ranges can be changed to Named Ranges, which allows them to be dynamic and edited by users who don't know VBA. For example, `Set SearchRange = [MyNamedRange]` and `weeknum = cell.Offset(0, [WeekNumberColumn].Column - cell.Column)`

Comment: Is there a way we could chat so I could show you the files better?

Comment: I can't spend so much time on this. I was just on my coffee break.

Comment: I see okay thanks. The code isn't working its so frustrating, I understand what you are doing but it wont work.